# runtime error on uva's minesweeper

Tags: c++, gcc

I have written a program to solve uva's [minesweeper problem](http://pastebin.com/xWLEXCcp) (10189) in C++.

I have written the code, and it seems to work correctly on my machine. Unfortunately my submission seems to be giving me run-time error (uva does not mention the error message or reason in such cases). I am pasting the code here:

```
using namespace std;

void nullCheck(void *ptr)
{
    exit(0);
}

typedef unsigned int uint;

class Field
{
public:
    vector <vector<uint> > nghBombCnt; //neighbourBombCount
    vector <vector<bool> > isBomb;
    uint width;
    uint height;

public:
    Field(uint w, uint h)
    {
    }
    Field() { }

    ~Field()
    {
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    vector<Field> fieldList;

    do
    {
        Field curField;
        uint width, height;

        scanf("%u %u", &height, &width);
        curField.width  = width;
        curField.height = height;

        for (uint rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < curField.height; rowCtr++)
        {
            vector<bool> curBombRow;
            for (uint colCtr = 0; colCtr < curField.width; colCtr++)
            {
                char curSymb;
                scanf("%1s", &curSymb);
                switch (curSymb)
                {
                    case '.':
                        curBombRow.push_back(false);  break;
                    case '*':
                        curBombRow.push_back(true);   break;
                    default:                  break;
                }
            }
            curField.isBomb.push_back(curBombRow);
        }

        if (!(curField.width == 0 && curField.height == 0))
            fieldList.push_back(curField);
        else
            break;

    } while (1);

    for (uint fieldCtr = 0; fieldCtr < fieldList.size(); fieldCtr++)
    {
        Field curField = fieldList.at(fieldCtr);
        for (uint rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < curField.height; rowCtr++)
        {
            vector<uint> curRow;
            for (uint colCtr = 0; colCtr < curField.width; colCtr++)
            {
                uint bombCnt = 0;
                if (curField.isBomb[rowCtr][colCtr])
                {
                    curRow.push_back(0);
                    continue;
                }

                if (colCtr != 0 && curField.isBomb[rowCtr][colCtr - 1])
                    bombCnt++; //east

                if (rowCtr != 0 && curField.isBomb[rowCtr - 1][colCtr])
                    bombCnt++; //north

                if (rowCtr != curField.height - 1
                        && curField.isBomb[rowCtr + 1][colCtr])
                    bombCnt++; //south

                if (colCtr != curField.width - 1
                        && curField.isBomb[rowCtr][colCtr + 1])
                    bombCnt++; //west

                if (colCtr != curField.width - 1 && rowCtr != 0
                        && curField.isBomb[rowCtr -1][colCtr + 1])
                    bombCnt++; //north-east

                if (colCtr != 0 && rowCtr != curField.height - 1
                        && curField.isBomb[rowCtr + 1][colCtr - 1])
                    bombCnt++; // south-west

                if (colCtr != curField.width - 1
                        && rowCtr != curField.height - 1
                        && curField.isBomb[rowCtr + 1][colCtr + 1])
                     bombCnt++; //south-east

                if (colCtr != 0 && rowCtr != 0
                        && curField.isBomb[rowCtr - 1][colCtr - 1])
                     bombCnt++; //north-west

                curRow.push_back(bombCnt);
            }
            curField.nghBombCnt.push_back(curRow);
        }
        fieldList[fieldCtr] = curField;
    }

    for (uint fieldNo = 0; fieldNo < fieldList.size(); fieldNo++)
    {
        printf("Field #%u:\n", fieldNo + 1);
        Field curField = fieldList.at(fieldNo);

        for (uint rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < curField.height; rowCtr++)
        {
            for (uint colCtr = 0; colCtr < curField.width; colCtr++)
            {
                if (curField.isBomb[rowCtr][colCtr])
                    printf("*");
                else
                    printf("%u", curField.nghBombCnt[rowCtr][colCtr]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Valgrind to determine if you have any memory stomping errors?

Comment: Yes, I did after you mentioned this. There seems to be no memory errors.

Comment: You should add a link to the actual problem. Not everyone knows what UVA is.

Comment: I had actually done that initially. However, now uva's website seems to be done. That's why I have moved the question over to pastebin now (see edited question).